# Can I change my programs tray icon while it runs in c#?

Tags: c#, icons, system, tray

I want to make my programs tray icon change colors if a certain event occurs. Can I set my code to change the tray icon while it runs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the [NotifyIcon.Icon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.icon.aspx) property to the new icon to change it.